# The Blasted "dyld_fatal_error:" Issue -Anyone Have a Definitive Answer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

OK, this issue is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811589/cant-run-app-on-device-after-upgrade-to-xcode-7), [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738891/getting-dyld-fatal-error-xcode-6-3-2) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811589/cant-run-app-on-device-after-upgrade-to-xcode-7). However, none of the "answers" seemed to actually address the issue.

This weekend, I submitted my app for beta-test review -twice. It bounced each time. It is now back in review again, and hasn't bounced (fingers crossed).

Each time, was because of an immediate launch crash. Fair enough. I wrote a bad app.

Except I didn't. When I tested in debug, and even release mode on my device and in the simulator, everything worked.

I was finally able to reproduce the issue by archiving and then manually installing the archive through iTunes.

Once I did that, it suddenly started happening when I ran in release mode in the debugger.

Hate it when that happens.

In any case, it was the 'dyld_fatal_error'. In my case, no matter what I did, I couldn't get it to spit out any information at all about what library it was having issues with. The crash reports I got back from Apple were worthless.

What finally solved it for me was basically completely dismantling my app, and putting it back together again. I removed all linked libraries (they are still gone), revoked every one of my certs, and rebuilt the profiles. I de-linked my tests, and re-linked them.

I used to live in Africa. I have a for-real Ju-Ju stick, which I shook at the device for good measure.

Something in there worked (I think, I still have to get a pass from Apple). My money is on the Ju-Ju stick.

The question is: Does anyone know of a DEFINITIVE (not all these WAG responses) reason for this error, and how it can be diagnosed?